# Is there a way to fix Lacquered kitchen cabinets?

Tags: repair, kitchens, wooden-furniture

In the house I'm renting the kitchen has these kind of red colored kitchen furniture.
Parts of the doors have lost bits of the colored layer.

[image]
[image]

My question is what would any of you do to fix it?

Is painting with a similar color a possible solution? Is there even a paint that works there?
Is there any kind of plastic film that can be used?

Comment: it looks like it was spry painted, and no any repair attempt will be visible. You have to redo the whole surface

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how much "fix" you're willing to have. A complete fresh look without any "edges" where the present dings are will require a complete strip-down, sand, and re-prime/repaint. This will be expensive in time and/or money. And you might need to get the landlord's permission.

But if you are willing to allow the "edges" of the white spots to still be felt, you might be able to take a small part, like a drawer front, to a paint store. They could match the color and sheen, then you could dab a small bit of paint to cover only the spots. It won't be factory-fresh, but if you're reasonably careful applying the paint, the glaring spots will be gone.

Have the paint store test the paint on the back of the sample piece to check if the color is exactly correct.